# Is it possible to use my own CNN model in faster R-CNN?

Tags: faster-rcnn, conv-neural-network

Suppose I have a CNN model already trained. How can i use it as a classifier for faster r-cnn?

Answer (score 0):

you can use your trained CNN model as a backbone network for extracting features.
I hope this answers your question.